# Convert to date format in r

Tags: r, date-conversion

I have been trying to convert a date from factor format to date format but I've been facing errors every time. The data is of the format

```
Mon/Yr
201701
201602
201506
```

Currently the values are factor type. I want to convert them to date format. I've used following code but I've been getting NA values

```
as.character(x$`Mon/Yr`)
as.POSIXct(x$`Mon/Yr`, format = '%y%m')

Output: [1] NA NA NA
```

I've followed example solutions from many posts but I'm not able to fix it. Can you please suggest a fix for this?

Comment: You need a `day` alsso to convert to date i.e. `as.Date(paste0(x$"Mon/Yr", "01"), "%Y%m%d")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame("Mon/Yr" = c(201701, 201602, 101506))
df
```

```
> df
  Mon.Yr
1 201701
2 201602
3 101506
```

```
df2 <- df %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(Mon.Yr = lubridate::parse_date_time(Mon.Yr, '%Y%m'),
                Mon.Yr = base::format(Mon.Yr, "%Y-%m"))
df2
```

```
> df2
   Mon.Yr
1 2017-01
2 2016-02
3 1015-06
```